# Sitecore commerce 9 certificate expired

Tags: sitecore-commerce, xconnect, sitecore-install-framework

I have an instance of sitecore commerce 9.0.1 installed on my local machine. Two days back I found that all the certificates are expired.

I created new Self-Signed Certificates and deleted the old ones and also remapped the thumbprint in the config files of SxP,xConnect, commerce roles etc.

Business Tool doesn't open, nothing in analytics works, product are empty etc.

I can see lots of error related to xConnect, xDb and all.

Please share your thoughts on the right way to replace expired certificates in sitecore commerce 9 ?

Comment: Maybe this https://mercury-ecommerce.com/resources/troubleshooting-sitecore-experience-commerce-9-installation helps?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the new self trusted and client certificates, then make sure you update the following config files:

**Xconnect**:

- sc\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config
- xconnect\App_Config\AppSettings.config
- xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config
- xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\ProcessingEngine\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config

**Identity Server**:

- identityserver\Config\production\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml

After doing so, make sure **you have the right certificates on IIS**.

[image]

The next thing I would double check is if you **self-trusted certificate has a private key** and if all generated **certificates have the right read-write access**:

[image]

[image]

You can find a more detailed explanation about all those certificate issues on this blogpost: https://coveoticore.wordpress.com/2019/02/19/how-to-fix-a-certificate-issue-on-a-sitecore-9-1-instance/

Comment: The solution you provided gave some idea about updating certificates in Sitecore XP.

But here I have issue with updating certificates for Sitecore Commerce 9 update 1 instance, where we have multiple certificates to handle.

Do you have any idea about this ?